# Different Proof Systems for the same Logic

Tags: logic, philosophy

Some standard kinds of proof systems include  natural deductive systems, sequent systems, axiomatic systems, and so on. There are various approaches to each of these kinds of proof systems. The rules/axioms of these systems can be tailored to the specific needs of those who use/study them. Model theorists like to use semantic tableaux and axiomatic systems; proof theorists like to use sequent systems. Most people argue using some sort of natural deduction. These systems all coalesce into an interplay between the semantics and syntax of a logic $\mathcal L$. Some systems are sound and complete, and there are systems everywhere in-between.

A well-known axiomatization of Classical Logic with Modus Ponens as its inference rules is as follows:

P1. $\varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi)$

P2. $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$

P3. $(\neg \psi \to \neg \varphi) \to (\varphi \to \psi)$

If one takes only P1 and P2, Positive Implicational Logic is achieved. However, an equivalent axiomatization puts things in a different light:

A1. $\varphi\to \neg\neg \varphi$

A2. $\neg \varphi \to (\varphi \to \psi)$

A3. $(\neg \varphi \to \varphi) \to (\psi \to \varphi)$

A4. $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$

Here, the validity of adding an assumption (formalized by P1) is a consequence of a kind of “Modus Mirabilis”, which is formalized as A3, as opposed to being assumed. In natural deductive systems, P1 may be proven using the Deduction Theorem/Conditional Introduction.

I suppose my question is akin to “is math invented or discovered?” But, in this case, it is to be seen whether or not a logic is prior to its possible proof systems. Equivalently, I wonder whether or not proof systems/inference patterns are prior to logics.

As an aside, does anyone know whether the second axiomatization would be complete if A4 were replaced with Hypothetical Syllogism as an inference rule?

Comment: Your main question ("I suppose my question is akin to “is math invented or discovered?” But, in this case, it is to be seen whether or not a logic is prior to its possible proof systems. Equivalently, I wonder whether or not proof systems/inference patterns are prior to logics.") isn't really appropriate for this site; it's far too subjective. Your secondary question is fine, though.

Comment: Should I edit the post and post the other part to philosophy stack exchange? I do want to hear different opinions on the matter from those that would have them.

Comment: "Model theorists like to use semantic tableaux" - I know lots of model theorists, and I've read lots of model theory papers, and none of them have ever mentioned semantic tableaux. For the most part, model theorists view proof systems as irrelevant to their work.

Comment: In my view, there are two things of primary importance: (1) the patterns of informal reasoning we do at the meta level, and (2) the semantic consequence relation $\models$. It's wonderful that we can define a provability relation $\vdash$ such that (0) $\vdash$ is easy to work with (i.e. generated by suitably computable rules), (1) the patterns of reasoning at the meta-level can be modeled in $\vdash$, and (2) $\vdash=\models$ (the completeness theorem holds). But it doesn't surprise me that there are lots of ways to define $\vdash$, and I don't really care about the details of the definition.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I mentioned semantic tableaux since they are a natural way to build counter-models, but I guess I misspoke.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I think the question about whether or not logic is prior to proof system is a valid, but with a nuanced answer. When we talk about "a logic", we are implying the existence of a deductive system: a logic isn't just an arbitrary collection of statements that we single out as theorems.  However, we recognise many ways of presenting deductive systems and we don't know a lot about how to relate different approaches. Hilbert-style presentations are particularly embarrassing, because we have difficulty in deciding whether different axiomatisations result in the same set of theorems.

Comment: @RobArthan "When we talk about "a logic", we are implying the existence of a deductive system." I don't think that's (universally) true at all. For example, I wouldn't say that second-order logic with the standard semantics has a deductive system in any useful sense, but I wouldn't hesitate to call it a logic nonetheless. Or even better, consider [Shelah's recently-introduced logic $\mathbb{L}_\kappa^1$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.01177.pdf) that doesn't even have a syntax at all! It's exactly this breadth of application of the term that I think makes this sort of question not a good fit here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am using the term "deductive system" in a very broad sense: a relation that says "if such and such a set of formulas hold, then so does this formula" (or maybe "if such and such a set of formulas holds, then so does one of this set of formulas"). I am making no assumptions about the nature of that relation or about the structure of formulas.

Comment: I should have qualified my second comment, with a confession that I am not familiar with the work you are referring to. From a quick look at the paper, a "logic" is defined there as some kind of relation between a set of sentences and a set of models. I'm happy for my deductive system to be defined by reference to a notion of validity of sentences in a set of models, so I maintain that, *mutatis mutandis*, my original comment stands.

Comment: I agree with Noah that 'logic' is pretty vague, but I also think that a few useful comments can be made towards what seems to be the core of this question. I would say that we typically start out with certain ideas or concepts, and only then we try to formalize it using some language.  Of course, sometimes that formalization helps us to further develop that concept: to gain insights that we didn't have beforehand, and sometimes even to change our concept. But on the whole, I would say the 'logic' largely comes 'before' the 'logic system'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both systems that you mention are systems that were meant to formalize classical propositional logic. And I would say that our ideas and concepts regarding this logic (every statements is either true or false ; the truth-value of any complex statement is a function of the truth-values of the smaller statements it comprises, together with the operators working as truth-functional operators as typically spelled out in the familiar truth-tables, etc.) came before we tried to formalize them. Indeed, it took a good bit of playing around with the axioms of these kinds of Hilbert-style axiomatic systems to try and make them complete with just a few axioms, i.e. we clearly knew what our goal was, and tried to make our formalization fit the bill. So at least in this narrow context, I would say the 'logic' came before the 'logic system'.

For your (small) question at the end:

> As an aside, does anyone know whether the second axiomatization would be complete if A4 were replaced with Hypothetical Syllogism as an inference rule?

I take this to mean the following system:

A1. $\varphi\to \neg\neg \varphi$

A2. $\neg \varphi \to (\varphi \to \psi)$

A3. $(\neg \varphi \to \varphi) \to (\psi \to \varphi)$

A4. $(\varphi \to \psi) \to ((\psi \to \chi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$

No, that system is not complete. It cannot prove the original axiom A4, and here is why.

Suppose we are working with a 3-valued system where every variable and statement evaluates to either $0$, $1$, or $2$.

Suppose the $\neg$ operator works as follows:

\begin{array}{c|c}
p&\neg p\\
\hline
0&1\\
1&0\\
2&2\\
\end{array}

And suppose the $\to$ operator works like this:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
p&q&p\to q\\
\hline
0&0&0\\
0&1&2\\
0&2&2\\
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
1&2&0\\
2&0&0\\
2&1&2\\
2&2&0\\
\end{array}

Now let's evaluate each of the axioms:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
p& p & \to & \neg & \neg & p\\
\hline
0&0&\color{red}0&0&1&0\\
1&1&\color{red}0&1&0&1\\
2&2&\color{red}0&2&2&2\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cc|ccccc}
p&q&\neg & p & \to & (p & \to & q)\\
\hline
0&0&1&0&\color{red}0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&\color{red}0&0&2&1\\
0&2&1&0&\color{red}0&0&2&2\\
1&0&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&1\\
1&2&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&2\\
2&0&2&2&\color{red}0&2&0&0\\
2&1&2&2&\color{red}0&2&2&1\\
2&2&2&2&\color{red}0&2&0&2\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cc|ccccccccc}
p&q&(\neg & p & \to & \neg & q) & \to & (q & \to & p)\\
\hline
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&\color{red}0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&0\\
0&2&1&0&0&2&2&\color{red}0&2&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&2&1&0&\color{red}0&0&2&1\\
1&1&0&1&0&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&1\\
1&2&0&1&2&2&2&\color{red}0&2&2&1\\
2&0&2&2&2&1&0&\color{red}0&0&2&2\\
2&1&2&2&0&0&1&\color{red}0&1&0&2\\
2&2&2&2&0&2&2&\color{red}0&2&0&2\\
\end{array}

OK, I skipped the axiom for $(\varphi \to \psi) \to ((\psi \to \chi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$ since that table would be 27 lines long, but if you were to work that one out you'll find that, like these first three axioms, it always evaluates to $0$.

We can call such statements (that always evaluate to $0$) '$0$-tautologies'. That is, all axioms turn out to be $0$ -tautologies.

Moreover, notice from the table of $\to$, that the only time that $p\ to q$ has the value of $0$, and $p$ has the value of $0$, is when $q$ has the value of $0$ as well. This means that with Modus Ponens as our only inference rule (which is what is assumed here with all these Hilbert-style systems), you can only infer something that is a $0$-tautology from any other $0$-tautologies. And that means that in any proof in this system, *every* statement will have to be a $0$-tautology.

OK, but now let's take a look at the original axioms A4, which was $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$.  Is that a $0$-tautology?  No, it is not. Consider the case where $p$ has the value of $2$, $q$ has the value of $0$, and $r$ has the value of $1$. Then $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (q \to r))$ works out to $(2 \to (0 \to 1)) \to ((2 \to 0) \to (0 \to 1)) = (2 \to 2) \to (0 \to 2) = 0 \to 2 = 2$

This means that $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$ is not a $0$-tautology, and hence cannot occur as any line in any proof within this system.  But since $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$ is a tautology in the classical 2-valued system (after all, it was used as an axiom in the original system), this system is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Is there a general way to decide truth table assignments to determine provability for an arbitrary axiomatic propositional logic?

Comment: @PW_246 Mostly trial and error!